# Что неправильно в этой структуре?

Tags: javascript

```
ch[1] = {

    "dfgasd HD", //Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token , 
        {"sdgsdgsdg sd",0,350},
        {"sadd dd dsdcff",350,700},
        {"sdasj osa djv",1050,250} 
};
```

**Как исправить?**

p.s. хотел, чтобы по **ch[1][0]** отдавалось *dfgasd HD*, а по **ch[1][1][0-2]** отдавалось *sdgsdgsdg sd*, *0* или *350*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Нужно присваивать массив, а не объект.

```
ch[1] = [
  "dfgasd HD",
  ["sdgsdgsdg sd",0,350],
  ["sadd dd dsdcff",350,700],
  ["sdasj osa djv",1050,250] 
];
```